# slow loading of angular datatable with large data with ng-repeat

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat, angular-datatables

I am dealing with a project  contains angular datatable . Problem with this data table it contains about 2500 rows to display. it is taking nearly 1 min to load. pagination is also applyed it contains 500 pages each page display 5 rows based on filtering .i have tried vs-repeat and limti to filter but no luck. i cant apply server side procesing because i am getting ajax error .Any help? please

Comment: Why are you getting an AJAX error? without AJAX, there is no use of AngularJS

Comment: i  tried to use deferrender to increase speed than i got ajax error

Comment: You should never use `ng-repeat` on large datasets. Use dataTables' built in render instead, i.e native rendering.

Comment: @davidkonrad a link to a reference would be much of a help :)

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Instead of using ng-repeat and angualar datatable tried to use ui-grid it works and loading speed of table is increased now.if anyone go with performance issues try to use ui-grid.hope this helps someone.